# Filling an array with NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have NSDictionary that get it data from JSON and now i want to mange that data and populate `tableView`. However, i face unpredicted obstacles. My point is - to make an arrays and methods with proper values (arrays of images, of text values, etc.). Currently I'm using AFNetworking. In one method i get JSON data:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

self.dataDict = (NSDictionary*)responseObject;
```

For attempt to create clear code i want to separate other methods by functions. I tried:

```
-(void)setImageView{
    if (self.dataDict){
self.dataDictArray  = [[self.dataDict valueForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then, when i want to use `NSLog` i do following:

```
NSLog(@"Check the array %@", [self.dataDictArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

It throw me an error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Obviously, it means that there is no object at index 0 in my array. But when i did:

```
NSLog(@"Check the array %@", self.dataDictArray);
```

It show me in console, that my array populate with single "id" number 3, which is actually first id in `NSDictionary`.

I want to understand, how to correct proper arrays that contain data from NSDictionary and what i did wrong?

Response obj. look like this:

```
(
        {
        id = 3;
        dog = "\U041a\U0430\U043a\U043e\U0439-\U0442\U043e \U043c\U0443\U0434\U0430\U043a \U043d\U0430\U043a\U0440\U0443\U0442\U0438\U043b";
        image = "cute_dog/116.jpg";
        score = 586;
    },
        {
        id = 115;
        dog = "\U0422\U0430\U043d\U044f \U041a\U043b\U044e\U043a\U0432\U0438\U043d\U0430";
        image = "cute_dog/115.jpg";
        score = 481;
    },
```

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put a portion of `responseObject` ? Do NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

Comment: @iphonic edit applied, please take a look

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28764205/790842, it will clear your doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally as per you say you have `Array of Dictionaries`. So you should follow these steps to fetch data.

**`Step 1.`**

```
self.dataDictArray = (NSArray*)responseObject;
```

**`Step 2.`**

```
self.dataDict=[self.dataDictArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

**`Step 3.`**

```
NSLog(@"ID = %@",[self.dataDict valueForKey:@"id"]);
```

**Simple.**

Cheers.

Comment: It helps, but why do u bother to make an array from dict?  Previously NSDictionary work just fine and i could see an output in NSLog.

Comment: As per your response it returns array not dictionary, so base should be array only, you were doing it incorrectly.. from json notion, if data starts from `(` its an array, and if starts from `{` its a dictionary.

Comment: one more question, when i look at URL in browser JSON plugin i could see, that it actualy start by [ then { . And in NSLog output it is( then {. Does that mean, when it start by [ then { (in browser) it is an array?

Comment: Both `[` and `(` denotes array. iOS converts `[` to `(`.

Comment: Yes browser shows array as `[`. Its just different representation for same thing, like we have different programming language for same thing..

Answer (score 1):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>
> Obviously, it means that there is no object at index 0 in my array

Your understanding of the error is wrong. There **is** an object at index 0, it just isn't an NSDictionary instance, but an NSNumber (the number 3 you mentioned). NSNumber does not have a method called objectAtIndex:, so that's the cause for the error.

Check your JSON parsing, you probably did something wrong there.

Comment: "Obviously, it means that there is no object at index 0 in my array". Obviously it doesn't mean anything like that. The reason is clearly that a message objectAtIndex is sent to an NSNumber object.